# Python - How to remove duplicate tuples in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I am having trouble removing tuples in the lists within a list.Basically I have this:

```
a = [[(4, 7), (4, 5)], [], [], [], [], [(4, 1)], [(4, 5), (4, 3)], [], [], [], [], [(4, 3), (4, 1)]]
```

i want every tuple only once.I also would like to remove the empty lists,something like that:

```
b = [[(4, 7)],[(4, 1)],[(4, 5)],[(4, 3)]]
```

the order doesn't matter but it's not just for this particular list(i want the code to work with any list made of lists with many tuples in them like this one). 
I tried set() but i can't figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
inp = [[(4, 7), (4, 5)], [], [], [], [], [(4, 1)], [(4, 5), (4, 3)], [], [], [], [], [(4, 3), (4, 1)]]

out = []
for lst in inp:
    for tup in lst:
        if [tup] not in out: 
            out.append([tup])
print out
```

`[[(4, 7)], [(4, 5)], [(4, 1)], [(4, 3)]]`

Comment: idk why but somehow this is the only one that worked. thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

[Itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to the rescue:

```
from itertools import chain
list(set(chain.from_iterable(a)))
[(4, 5), (4, 7), (4, 1), (4, 3)]
```

If the nesting is really important:

```
[[t] for t in set(chain(*a))]
```

Comment: @NiklasB. yes, it is, thanks. I had planned to use `map`, but that didn't pan out. :)

Comment: Whenever uniqueness is important, start thinking set.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
[[x] for x in set(chain(*a))]
```